# How can VHF signal be amplified with respective gain by simple BJT circuit design?

Tags: power, amplifier, rf, radio, class-e

I am studying RF amplifiers. Most of the time, when I simulate several BJT amplifiers at a very high frequency, I do not get a good voltage or current gain. I have heard of Miller effect. What does it do and how can I design against this effect? Class E amplifier should be good one, but all I need is how to think about high frequency amplification. There are many web sites on internet, they are useless, too. They do not give the information to make and keep it simple.

Can you give me an example, how to design simply a VHF amplification?

Edit:

I am interested in electronics, but I am not academically educated.

Comment: If your circuit has a highpass-like response, then you would get higher amplitude with a square wave due it it containing high frequencies which are less attenuated.

Comment: lastime, in the picture you may be comparing an inductor current to a voltage? And that current *must* drive a 14.88 Ohm resistor? So the output should be 14.88 times the input current. Of course you will see bigger voltage numbers than current numbers in what you are comparing. But I don't think you've included everything you were looking at when writing. So I'm probably somewhat confused.

Comment: @periblepsis I would use a 50 ohm resistor, which should be an antenna at last by making an impedance matching. It should give the same result at the end.

Comment: @lastime I guess I don't follow. I will back away and let others who can read better than I can handle it.

Comment: You should post a screenshot of your schematic that includes the sine wave voltage source.

Comment: @SteKulov Hi, the sine voltage source has the same properties as the pulse one, except that the wave is a sine not a pulse. The sine wave was a 1V voltage with 7.125 MHz frequency which gave me less gain than the pulse, therefore the question above. TY.

Comment: A sine wave with the same properties of the pulse would have 0.5V amplitude and 0.5V offset. Is that what you have? You could avoid this ambiguity by posting  an image of exactly what you did.

Comment: @SteKulov 1V amplitude sine wave in LTSpice. No offset. Sorry. I would edit the post, but I think there is no need to do this. I hope this comment helps. There is a mate called DELTA12 above in the comments. I suppose, this person gave me an idea, why this problem with sine waves, was happening. TY.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, if there’s no offset then the sine wave swings below zero so that can also be contributing to any discrepancies. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good VHF RF transistors commercial available on internet. For example a 2N4427T RF transistor. Cascode amplifier are well suggested for amplifying high frequencies with small signal.

I calculated my own design at given tool link:

https://www.utmel.com/tools/bjt-cascode-amplifier-calculator?id=34

I have also simulated on LTSpice a working cascode amplifier. You will see the high power gain at output. The picture is below:

Violetta is input R7 power
Yellow is output R8 power.
[image: circuit]

I hope it helps others, too.

Comment: Wow good +1 .If you used a simple broadband                  stepdown transformer  on the output the gain would be even more .

Answer (score 1):

Some ways of reducing miller effect are driving from a low source impedance like in your case transforming down from 50 ohm or/and looking at common base. Running the collector into a higher load impedance will help voltage gain also. You could look at the well documented cascode connection which uses 2 devices but it is worth it because low power VHF transistors are cheap.